# Is it possible to create non-unit spheres in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to adapt some code posted here to create a sphere extending from -15 to +15 on the xyz-axes.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis equal,
    axis lines = center,
    width = 10cm,
    height = 10cm,
    view/h=15,
]
\addplot3[surf, opacity = 0.5,
    samples=30,
    domain=-15:15,
    y domain=0:3*pi/2,
    z buffer=sort]
  ({sqrt(15-15*x^2) * cos(deg(y))},
  {sqrt( 15-15*x^2 ) * sin(deg(y))},
 x);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I have seen some comments that TikZ or pgfplots are incapable of creating actual 3d plots. Is that correct, should I use asymptote, or is the mathematics above incorrect?

Comment: Why `15-15*x^2` while `x` running from `-15` to `15`? It will simply give `sqrt` negative numbers and the rest will be a mess.

Comment: @Symbol1 - I corrected that - x should range from -1 to 1 in this code to make the formula correct. However....your answer below does the job. As ever, thanks Symbol 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct coordinate is

```
({sqrt(15*15-x^2) * cos(deg(y))},
 {sqrt( 15*15-x^2 ) * sin(deg(y))},
 x);
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what is required. The mistake was in the mathematics.